# Permanently identify user

Tags: botframework

Im writing a bot, which acts as an interface between a user and an already existing web service.
My challenge now is to match for example a skype or slack user with an already existing user of the web service.

For that i need to know:

What is a unique identifier for lets say a slack user?
Is it the property "address", which is a cryptic mix of letters or is it the property "id" which is also a cryptic mix of letters?

Over the last few days, none of those 2 properties did change so im not sure.

I'd appreciate your help.

Greetings

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42366186/correct-id-to-send-message-to-a-skype-account/42367774#42367774