# Correct id to send message to a skype account

Tags: botframework

I am trying to test my bot by sending a message to my skype account. I can't find a way how to contact myself what is the `members.id` id suppossed to be? I tried Skype Name but can't find any other id suitable and the docs are not very helpful.

I started a conversation:

```
{
  "bot": {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "bot's name"
  },
  "isGroup": false,
  "members": [
    {
      "id": "123",           <----------------- WHAT SHALL BE HERE?
      "name": "My Account"
    }
  ],
  "topicName": "News Alert"
}
```

The id for the conversation is `{ "id": "123" }`.

I could find the bot from the Skype app but I never receive anything.

Comment: Is the bot in your skype contact list?

Comment: Yes, it is. I can even send a message to it. I don't have a webhook address yet but I should be able to send the message anyways, right? Or is there any kind of authorization from the user part?

Comment: Hmm, as you can send a message to bot then try to get Id of your skype by putting breakpoint on where you handle the received message, and check the [Activity].from.id property and use it there

Comment: Yop, I will do it for sure. I haven't setup the webhook endpoint. In the meantime do you where I can find the correct id?

Comment: Sadly there is no such option to get the user ID before setting up the bot (in this case: connecting the user to bot). Please take a look at the answer for details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the ID of user by checking the `Activity.From.Id` property when s/he sends a message.
Also please note that in case of Skype and Facebook user IDs are altered for each user.
So each user has different ID for each Bot, and that ID is not the Skype (or Facebook) ID, as mentioned in [documentation](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/bot-framework-guide-id/)

Comment: would be handle to see how various web services respond to a bot channel: Facebook, Skype, Twilio, Slack, etc.